# childs position on a DIV with RTL direction

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a custom tag box that is shown in the picture for my website.

[image]

There is a search bar on the bottom of the box in which the user searches for tags.
below that there is a DIV which shows the search results recieved with ajax. i need
it's direction to be set to RTL which makes the scroll bar appear on the left side.
but as you can see in the picture there is always an extra white space on the right side although there is no margin-right set for that. the problem occurs in chrome. works fine in firefox!

I couldn't include the full code here but there is a simple example on jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/XP3Hc/

Comment: Remove `padding: 10px;` and `margin:5px;`

Comment: I did that, but still there is an extra white space on the right side which is as wide as the width of the Scrollbar! :(

Comment: Check below, I posted a solution and I see it correctly

Comment: It seems fine in firefox. but in chrome still i have this problem! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question right and you want the space on the right removed.

Change to this:

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.container{
    width: 378px; 
    height: auto; 
    float: right; 
    margin-top: -1px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: solid 1px #999;
    max-height: 200px;
}
.container div{
    width: 100%;
    direction: rtl;
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #999; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XP3Hc/5/)**

Comment: my problem is just in google chrome! now the white space is moved from the right side to the left!

Comment: I think this problem has something to do with the Chrome itselt. :(

Comment: thank you! I just updated your code a bit and my problem is solved! thank you! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/9z8Lq/